# In antd Table, can you combine Pagination and Footer somhow?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm trying to save vertical space in an antd Table. I'm trying to render an "export CSV" link at the bottom of the Table alongside the Paginator. You can get the itemrender for each item in the Paginator, but you can't render adequately. i.e. this:

```
    itemrender(page, type, originalElement) {
        if (type === "prev") {
            return <><a onClick={() => ExportCSV()}>Export CSV</a>{originalElement}</>
        }
        return <>{originalElement}</>;
    }
```

Results in a cramped, line-breaking manner because both the a tag and the a tag of the 'prev' are both rendered inside of the same `<li>` block.

I tried rendering a Paginator in the Table footer, but that Paginator doesn't connect to the Table.

Is there a way to move the Paginator into the footer and still have it connected to the Table somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a very similar use-case and landed up here for searching the same,
Here's how I managed to combine Pagination with Table Footer.

```js
import { Table, Pagination, Row } from 'antd';

const TableFooter = ({
  paginationProps
}) => {
    return( 
      <Row
        justify='space-between'
      >
         <Row>
            Some Left Side Content...
         </Row>
         <Pagination 
            {...paginationProps}
         />
      </Row>
    )
}

const App = () => {
  const pagination = {
    current: 1,
    total: 0,
    pageSize: 10,
    showTotal: (total, range) => `Total ${total} Pokemons`,
    onChange: onPaginationChange
  }
  
  const columns = [
    {title: "ID", dataIndex: "id"},
    {title: "Name", dataIndex: "name"}
  ]
  
  const data = [
    {id: 1, name: "Pikachu"},
    {id: 2, name: "Psyduck"}
  ]

  return (
    <Table 
      columns={columns}
      data={data}
      footer={() => 
        <TableFooter />
      }
      pagination={false}
    />
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

Comment: And you can always filter the data that you are passing to Table based on pagination, or even implement Server side pagination

Answer (score 1):

You can't, as you mentioned, if you want the `Pagination` to be available in the footer you need to implement the "connection" with the table by your self.

Notice that you have all [Pagination API](https://ant.design/components/pagination/) available to you while using the `Table` component, therefore you can customize it to a smaller size:

```
<Table pagination={{ size: "small" }}/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The footer is a whole extra row, and the pagination is a whole extra row, with lots of space next to it. I know the design isn't going to fly with that, so short of overriding something to combine the two, it's a no-go. The Paginator seems designed for lists, and I don't seem to see a way to connect into the table itself to get the paging, so it seems like I'd need to manipulate the dataset somewhere and only give the table the data for the current page. You lose sorting and everything else if you go that route. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Yes you right, just chunk the data source for pagination